# Cakephp multiple views per controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, view

I have a controller which has 3 functions. I wish to show 3 different views and layouts in each function depending on whether the user comes from mobile, website or facebook. I am passing in already where the user is coming from.

I am unsure how I would then show a particular view and layout for each. Here is some code that I started to do to change the layout. I have the views in a folder called res.

```
function availability() {

    if ($_REQUEST['from'] == 'facebook') {
        $this->layout = 'facebook';
        print_r ('face');
    }elseif ($_REQUEST['from'] == 'website'){
        $this->layout = 'website';
        print_r ('web');
    }elseif ($_REQUEST['from'] == 'mobile'){
        $this->layout = 'mobile';
        print_r ('mobile');         
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$this->render()` to change the view.

```
$this->layout = 'facebook';
$this->render( 'res/facebook' );
```

You could also put all the views for different layouts to their own folders and set the viewpath so that you don't have to choose the views manually in each function:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->viewPath = $_REQUEST[ 'from' ];
}
```

Now the view for action "availability" for the Facebook layout is fetched from `facebook/availability.ctp`.